# Is there a Remove() method that will also return the removed substring?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Given `string s = "ABCDEF"`, I would like something like the `Remove()` method, which also returns the removed string. For example, something like:

```
string removed = s.NewRemove(3); // removed is "DEF"
```

or:

```
string removed = s.NewRemove(3,2); // removed is "DE"
```

or maybe:

```
s.NewRemove(3, out removed);
```

Comment: Please write two different questions - one for Python and one for C#. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: @mjwills: I'll remove the python tag, but I already have a python answer, so it'll look odd if I remove the mention of python from the question. What should I do?

Comment: I would write a new question, and comment on the answerer to come repeat his/her answer on the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily write your own extension method

```
public static string Remove(this string source, int startIndex, int count,out string removed)
{
   if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex));
   if (count < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
   if (count > source.Length - startIndex) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

   removed = source.Substring(startIndex, count);   
   return source.Remove(startIndex, count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, this is done with slicing:

```
s = 'ABCDEF'
removed = s[3:]
```

You can wrap it in a function:

```
def remove(string, start, length=None):
    if length is None:
        end = None

    else:
        end = start + length

    return string[start:end]

remove(s, 3, 2)
```

Output:

```
DE
```